# How to send requirement failed exception back to sender?

Tags: scala, akka

I have this piece of code :

```
override def create(policy: Policy): Future[Policy] = {
  //require that an id has not been assigned to this policy

  if (policy.id != None) { 
    //ugly and does not type check, but trying to convey the general idea 
    sender ! require(policy.id == None) 
    require(policy.id == None)
  else { 
    Future {
      policy //dummy code for simplicity sake
    }
  } 
}
```

I'd like to send a message back to the sender that a requirement was not fulfilled. I want to try and do this in the most idiomatic way as possible. I want to ideally terminate execution in this actor and send the requirement message back to the sender of this  actor.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have isn't constructed to work, and it doesn't match your comment. The first path of the conditional does not provide a `Future[Policy]`, nor should it. If this method is invoked from your `receive()` method, then you need to refactor so that the failure is recognized early.

```
case class PolicyResult(reason: String)

override def create(policy: Policy): Future[Policy] = Future(policy)

def receive: {
  case p: Policy if p.id == None =>
    sender ! PolicyResult("Policy must have id defined")
  case p: Policy =>
    ...
    val vp = create(p)
}
```